# Jquery Slide toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slide

I'm trying to fire on my Slide toggle but is not working as is expected. Each click works only for the first div.

HTML Code :

```
<div id="toggle">
    <span id="down"></span>
    <a id ="slide" href="#">Passende Produkte zum Gutschein</br></a>
    <div id="inner">text tetxtext</div>

    <span id="down"></span>
    <a id ="slide" href="#">Passende Produkte zum Gutschein</a>
    <div id="inner">text tetxtext</div>
</div>
```

JS Code :

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#inner').slideToggle('fast');    
});
```

CSS :

```
#inner {
    display:none;
}
```

My result is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/fRfsa/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead, also you haven't loaded jQuery in the jsfiddle.

```
<div id="toggle">
    <span class="down"></span>
    <a class="slide" href="#">Passende Produkte zum Gutschein</br></a>
    <div class="inner">text tetxtext</div>

    <span class="down"></span>
    <a class="slide" href="#">Passende Produkte zum Gutschein</a>
    <div class="inner">text tetxtext</div>
</div>
```

Based on your markup you can use `next` or `siblings` method.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
   $(this).next('.inner').slideToggle('fast');
   // $(this).siblings('.inner').slideToggle('fast'); 
   event.preventDefault() // prevents the default action of event.       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wh5u2/